# resizing image with aspect ratio

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to resize the image but not increase it to above its original size - I also want to centre the image within its container. It this the best way to do it as it seems a bit jerky sometimes?

I have taken out the jquery js link.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .container {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background: #444;
            }
        </style>                
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="D:\large.png" />
        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
        var $orig_width=0;
        var $orig_height=0;
        var width;
        var height;
        var $img;

         $(window).load(function() {            
            $img = $('.container').find('img');     
            $orig_width=$img.width();
            $orig_height=$img.height(); 
            resize();           
         });

        function resize() {
            var width=$img.width();
            var height=$img.height();       
            var parentWidth  = $img.parent().width();
            var parentHeight = $img.parent().height();

            newWidth  = parentWidth;
            newHeight = newWidth/width*height;

            if (newHeight>$orig_height) newHeight=$orig_height;     
            if (newWidth>$orig_width) newWidth=$orig_width; 

            margin_top  = (parentHeight - newHeight) / 2;
            margin_left = ((parentWidth  - newWidth ) / 2);

            $img.css({'margin-top' :margin_top  + 'px',
                      'margin-left':margin_left + 'px',
                      'height'     :newHeight   + 'px',
                      'width'      :newWidth    + 'px'});
        }

        $(window).resize(function() {           
            resize();           
        })      

    </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work OK now with JQuery version 1.7.2

Answer (score 1):

You just use table for container. Because easily you align it in table.
For setting the fixed width and height as attribute will bring the solution for fixed size image.

Answer (score 0):

I use in such a case `max-width:100%;` instead of `width:100%;`.

Answer (score 0):

Check my plugin for that, using "CENTER" mode: https://github.com/stereoactivo/jquery.resize-image-aspect-ratio